# subsonic IQueryable cast

Tags: subsonic

We have this:

```
repository.Add<Customer>(c);
...
IQueryable<Customer> result1 = repository.All<Customer>();
Console.WriteLine( result1.Count() );
IQueryable<ICustomer> result2 = result1.Cast<ICustomer>();
Console.WriteLine( result2.Count() ); // error here
```

That gives the following error:

> Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Data.Customer]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Data.ICustomer] Cast[ICustomer]] (System.Linq.IQueryable)'

Is it possible to work via interfaces?